# Как сделать скроллинг и css-анимацию плавными?

Tags: css3, анимация, javascript, html5

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/3wqndLyu/), о чём идёт речь – как сделать анимацию влево-вправо, которая реализована CSS3 transform, *плавной*?

---

Есть что-то похожее на большую таблицу, лишь часть которой видно через небольшое окно `<div style="overflow:auto">`.

«Таблица» сделана из div'ов колонок (`position:absolute`), внутри которых абсолютно спозиционированы по высоте отдельные ячейки — небольшие структуры из нескольких `<div>`.

Раньше число столбцов идеально вписывалось в ширину, и скроллинг был только вертикальный, родной браузерный. Теперь возникла необходимость неограниченно расширить число колонок.

Я хочу, чтобы:

1) вертикальный скроллинг был нативным браузерным (обычным);
 2) горизонтальный – дискретным по столбцам, и желательно, без полосы прокрутки браузера, а js/кнопками. И хорошо бы с плавным CSS3 transition;
 3) всё это не тормозило при большом числе невидимых деталей.

Сейчас проблема в том, что горизонтальный шаг, который я сделал назначением div'ам колонок свойства `transform: translateX(-300)`, несмотря на `transition: transform 1s`, выглядит в FireFox **очень скачкообразным**. Видимо, сказывается большое число невидимых ячеек, для которых почему-то всё равно что-то просчитывается.

> **Upd.** Тормоза в FireFox, а в Chrome всё прилично плавно.

В какую сторону копать? Ускорит ли CSS анимацию, если делать колонки, которые точно за кадром, `display:none`?

---

**Upd. 2.** [Видео доклад](http://youtu.be/R6TXuXV1bbY) с CSS conf US 2014 проливает свет на проблему. Paul Irish про параллакс эффект и скорость рендеринга в браузерах (на англ.)

**Upd. 3.** Исследования и рекомендации для плавных анимаций и прокрутки в браузерах: [jankfree.org](http://jankfree.org/) (на англ.)

**Upd. 4.** добавил [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/3wqndLyu/). Разумеется, упрощённый. В настоящем и ячеек больше, и состоят они не из одного div'а, а чуть более сложные конструкции, все кликабельные.

Comment: > вертикальный скроллинг был плавным;

Минимум абсолютно позиционированных элементов. 95%, что если там нужно абсолютное позиционирование, это можно сделать через одного родителя. Тормоза скорее всего из-за того, что пересчитывается миллиард абсолютно позиционированных элементов при каждом скролле.

Comment: @Etki, вертикальный и так плавный, я имею в виду, что его хочется оставить нативным браузерным скроллом. В то же время как-то вмешаться в горизонтальный, сделав его "прилипающим" к дискретным позициям.

Абс. поз. нужно чтобы разместить отдельные ячейки — во многих строках они пропущены, поэтому нужно их по высоте ставить.

Comment: @sergiks, я бы попробовал как минимум замещать пропущенные блоки на пустые.

Comment: @Etki т.е. больше DOM элементов, но в обычном flow лучше, чем меньше DOM-nodes, но abs-позиционированных? Почему?

Comment: @sergiks, потому что, если память мне не врет, позиционирование обычных элементов может выполняться разом и значительно дешевле абсолютного позиционирования. Я не знаю тонкостей рендеринга, но если в одном потоке скролл - это просто по факту смещение viewport'а, то с кучей абсолютно позиционированных элементов этих потоков становится миллиард. Затык, насколько понимаю, в том, что браузеры начинают пересчитывать положения всех элементов, хотя по факту надо просто сместить область видимости в одинаковой степени для всех элементов (что, видимо, и сделано в хроме).